# Animations are very slow when my app (Ionic framework) is insalled in Android Devices

Tags: android, jquery, canvas, mobile, ionic-framework

I have created a snowfall animation in js for my ionic framework app and when we install it in Android phones the animations is very slow, in browser its working fine. We have tried the animations in Jquery, canvas and CSS3 too, but the result is same.

Does anyone have any clues as to why it is so slow when the app is installed in real devices.